# Adding some japanese characters to a text

Tags: errors, environments, german, japanese

I've been writing a text in German and want to add some Japanese characters. I created a new environment (got the code from somewhere here, forgot to save the link to the original page) an the characters appear as I wanted them. The Problem is that after I write a character in that environment I can't write "ä","ö","ü" without getting an error.

Here's an example

```
\documentclass[a4paper, leqno, oneside]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%% Jap. Chara %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

\usepackage{CJK} 
\newcommand{\japanese}[1]{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}#1\end{CJK}} 

\lstset{language=Pascal} 
\lstset{literate=% 
{Ö}{{\"O}}1 
{Ä}{{\"A}}1 
{Ü}{{\"U}}1 
{ß}{{\ss}}2 
{ü}{{\"u}}1 
{ä}{{\"a}}1 
{ö}{{\"o}}1 
} 

\begin{document} 

\part{Vorwort} 

\subsection{Hallo} \label{sec:Hallo} 
Die Japanische Sprache hat verschiedenen Alphabete, eines davon nennt sich \japanese{カタカナ}. Es läuft dabei.... 
\end{document}
```

If you remove "läuft" after the created environment everything works fine, if it's there I get the following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence. 
\CJK@XX ...r `#1\endcsname {`#2}\CJK@ignorespaces 
                                                  \fi 
l.33 ...avon nennt sich \japanese{カタカナ}. Es lä 
                                                  uft dabei.... 
The control sequence at the end of the top line 
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have 
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct 
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, 
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

To be honest, I have no idea why this isn't working. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks, Sito

Comment: I've once been told that “jap” is not one of Japanese people favorite word.

Comment: `\usepackage{CJKutf8}`

Comment: I'm not trying to offend anyone here, it's just a short, convenient expression for a environment for obvious reasons.  But I'll edit it right away.